# Point3D can not be resolved in eclipse/JAVA

Tags: java

I need to store points (that are derived from calculations). I have read on google about Point3D and I need this in my code, unfortunately 'it cannot be resolved'. I have tried importing java.vecmath.Point3d but again it can't be resolved.

I read further on the internet to find I need to download the package, I thought I had done this but it still could not be resolved. I am using eclipse and JAVA package.

Can someone advise me through how to get Point3D to work....or an alternative method?

Comment: Note that the `d` in `Point3d` refers to the `double` primitive. Also consider `Point3f` for `float`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `javax.vecmath` package from [Java 3D](https://java3d.java.net/).

Comment: Perhaps add a [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html)?

Comment: I was looking for one, but got interrupted ;-)